# jquery mobile and Internet Explorer are not working at all

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile

I know that IE 7-9 are Grade A supported. But with my site it is not working, I can’t figure out for the life of me why. Here is the link: http://www.fuelingminds.com/userpages.cfm I’ve done previous projects using alpha 4 and everything looked just fine, but I switched to beta 1 now. are there any known issues that are out there or am I just missing something obvious in my code?

Note: I tried disabling ajax to see if that was the cause, but still the same skewed look, I’ve tried on IE 7 and 9 on multiple computers, tried using jquery mobile from a local source instead as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/loginandError.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="login" data-ajax="false">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a onClick="window.history.back()" data-icon="back" data-direction="reverse" >back</a>
        <a href="index.cfm">home</a>
        <h1>Fueling The Future - Login</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" align="center">
        <form action="loginAct.cfm" method="post" data-ajax="false">
            <input type="text"  value="youremail@email.com" name="email">
            <input type="password" value="password" name="pass">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="login" name="login" data-inline="true">
            <br>
            <a href="" style="text-decoration:none;">Register To Apply Today!</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>


<!---        <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="register" data-ajax="false">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Fueling The Future</h1>
            <!--<div data-role="navbar">
                <ul data-inset="true" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;"> 
                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">The Program</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Page 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>       
                </ul>
            </div>-->
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <cfform action="regAction.cfm" method="post" data-ajax="false">    
                <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                <cfinput type="text" label="E-mail" name="email" >           
                <label for="pass">password</label>
                <cfinput type="password" name="pass" >
                <label for="passChk">enter password again</label>
                <cfinput type="password" name="passChk" >                 
                <label for="fName">First Name</label>
                <cfinput type="text" name="fName">
                <label for="lName">Last Name</label>
                <cfinput type="text" name="lName">
                <br>
                <cfinput type="submit" name="submit" value="register" data-inline="true">
            </cfform>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">

        </div>
    </div>--->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is [this page](http://scrum-it-demo.bsgroupti.ch/) working with your IE9?

If yes, it is unfortunately Alpha3 of jQuery Mobile, but perhaps these fixes will work for you:

```
// Fix for IE9 and experimental jQuery Mobile Datepicker
//customize jQuery Mobile to let IE7+ in (Mobile IE)
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    //reset type=date inputs to text
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
    $.extend($.mobile, {
        //extend gradeA qualifier to include IE7+
            gradeA: function() {
                //IE version check by James Padolsey, modified by jdalton - from http://gist.github.com/527683
                    var ie = (function() {
                        var v = 3, div = document.createElement('div'), a = div.all || [];
                            while (div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE '+(++v)+']><br><![endif]-->', a[0]);
                                return v > 4 ? v : !v;
                    }());
                    //must either support media queries or be IE7+
                    return $.support.mediaquery || (ie && ie >= 7);
            }
    });
});
```

You have to put these lines of code between query.js and query.mobile.js.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have `<!DOCTYPE html>` or else it wont read the html5 correctly.

Comment: I already caught that forgot to make the change on here. I realized the issue is coming from the Server, I tried running it on a linux server instead and it all renders fine in IE but when I have the same code on IIS it doesn’t render in Internet explorer, yet it oddly all does in every other browser.

Answer (score 5):

```
<meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<!--[if IE 7]><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>

    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .clear {
            zoom: 1;
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

paste this to your layout page